# Problem executing "Pyinstaller" from command prompt

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using cmd to install `pyinstaller`, the installation went fine but the moment I tried to turn a `.py` file to `.exe` an error appeared:

```
"pyinstaller" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
executable program or batch file.
```

This has never happened before.Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try,
`python -m pyinstaller yourPythonFile.py`